# Trigger after manual stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I am trying to trigger a stage in gitlab ci process after a manual step and having some issues finding the correct step.

i build fine and then want to do a manual deploy with option to stop. if the deploy is successful i want to trigger my test that are in another repo.

The trigger step appears to be running after the build, and a visual of what the pipeline is doing

[image: pipeline]

this is my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
stage:
    - build-dev
    - deploy-dev
    - test-dev 

build:dev:
    stage: build-dev
    script:
        - my_script
    except:
        - master

deploy:dev:
    <<: *deploy-dev
    stage: deploy-dev
    variables:
        <<: *dev-variables
    environment:
        name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
        on_stop: stop:dev   
    except:
        - master

stop:dev
    stage: deploy-dev
    <<: *shutdown_script
    when: manual
    environment:
        name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
        action: stop

test:dev:
    stage: test-dev
    trigger:    "qa/my_repo_qa"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `when: manual` it is, by default, implies `allow_failure: true` and is *nonblocking*. This means other jobs in later stages can run even though the manual jobs have not been run.

If you want the manual job to *block* the pipeline instead, you must set `allow_failure: false`.

Also note that, similarly, triggered pipelines also have a default *nonblocking* behavior. If you want to wait for the triggered pipeline to successfully complete before the parent pipeline moves on, you must set `strategy: depend` under the `trigger:` key.